# ggplot2 and CSV "inventing" data that isn't in my input

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I'm attempting to produce an attractive graph of bandwidth data across a number of machines and tests. My attempts seem to work for small manually entered amounts of data, but when I feed the "full" 1773 entries, I get results in my graph that don't seem to exist in the input data.

I believe this is likely because the different tests are each of different duration, but I can't seem to prove this. If I use the following [input data](https://pastebin.com/raw/nfcsSGE6) as csv (sorry, off-site because of size) I end up with a strange upwards-curve on my geom_smooth line, and additional data points that I can't actually see in my .csv input data. (I have much more data in real life, this is a subset that produces the strange behaviour)

I would expect the first four tries (try01-try04) to flat-line at zero, and try05 to carry on at around 1GBit/sec. Here's my code

```
library("ggplot2")
library("RColorBrewer")

speed = read.csv(file="data.csv")

svg("all_results.svg",width=24)
ggplot(speed,
    aes(x = Second, y = Bandwidth, group=Test, colour=Test)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth()
dev.off()
```

[Here's the image produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTRT2.png)

@Gregor seems to be exactly right in that the seconds are interpreted as text, when they should represent the number of the seconds since the start of that test.
Here's some example input data - please note the times are not always on a .00 second boundary due to the output of iperf.

```
structure(list(Machine = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "valhalla", class = "factor"), 
    User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "alice", class = "factor"), 
    Test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "try01", class = "factor"), 
    Second = structure(c(1L, 2L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("0.00-1.00", 
    "1.00-2.00", "10.00-11.00", "11.00-12.00", "12.00-13.00", 
    "13.00-14.00", "14.00-15.00", "15.00-16.00", "16.00-17.00", 
    "17.00-18.00", "18.00-19.00", "19.00-20.00", "2.00-3.00", 
    "3.00-4.00", "4.00-5.00", "5.00-6.00", "6.00-7.00", "7.00-8.00", 
    "8.00-9.00", "9.00-10.00"), class = "factor"), Bandwidth = c(937, 
    943, 944, 943, 943, 943, 943, 944, 658, 943, 944, 943, 944, 
    644, 943, 943, 943, 944, 943, 943)), row.names = c(NA, 20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I'll try casting (or whatever R calls it) those to a float now.

Comment: Your x-axis looks categorical, which means it is probably a `factor` and is ordered alphabetically. You don't share any data, and we can't read any values off your chart, but I would guess that your `Second` column should be treated as numeric and you should convert it. If you share some sample data we can help with that.

Comment: (And by *don't share any data*, I mean in the question itself. `dput(droplevels(head(speed, 20)))` would be a great way to share the top 20 rows of your data, in a copy/pasteable way that shows the object structure and classes. And it doesn't require asking people to download and import some large data.

Comment: Ah, you're exactly correct @Gregor - my time is being treated as text. It's of the form "9.01-10.00" and "12.00-13.00" (i.e. **approximately** one second per sample). I'll update my question to include the dput as it's too large for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points have a single `x` value, not a range of x-values, so we'll separate your `Second` column into beginning and end of the interval and plot the points at the beginning. Calling your data `dd`"

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dd = dd %>%
  separate(Second, into = c("sec_start", "sec_end"), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(sec_start = as.numeric(sec_start),
         sec_end = as.numeric(sec_end))
```

After that the plotting should go just fine if you put `sec_start` or `sec_end` on the x-axis. (Or calculate the middle, whatever you want...)

If you want to visualize the durations, you could use `geom_segment` and `aes(x = sec_start, xend = sec_end, y = Bandwidth, yend = Bandwidth)`, but since everything is just about the same duration, it doesn't seem like this would add much value.

Comment: Thanks Gregor, your answer worked more or less verbatim. I now need to read up on tidyr and dplyr, and where that "%>" syntax comes from. I'm not yet deep enough into R for the landscape to make complete sense, and I'm still stuck in my more perl-aware thinking...

Comment: Glad it helped. I'd strongly recommend the package vignette [An Introduction to dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html). Covers all the `dplyr` basics, including `%>%`.